# MessageFilter with PointCloud + PoseMessage

Tags: ros, pose, pointcloud, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to register a map using point clouds that are coming from a Stereo Camera at 20 Hz and a pose estimator that fires at 160 Hz. My first code is something like:

```
tl.waitForTransform("odom", "bumblebee_optical_frame", time, ros::Duration(1.0));
tl.lookupTransform("odom", "bumblebee_optical_frame", ros::Time::now(), st);
Eigen::Affine3d e;
tf::transformTFToEigen(st, e);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*tmp, buffer, e);
```

where `tl` is a `TransformListener`, `odom` is the fixed world frame, `tmp` is the cloud that comes from the message (the piece of code is inside a callback function) and buffer is the output cloud that I will use with something like `map += buffer;`
where `map` is the global map.

Of course is a naive approach and I don't expect a perfect map, but what I see is that it seems like the every new cloud that is coming is registered, but with a delay so the effect is that I see the same object on the ground repeated many many times, while in Rviz I clearly see that the objects change during the trip.

If I remove the line `waitForTransform`, I see a very sparse map, but synchronized correctly (I can see one cloud every one or two meters).

Why is this happening? The pose is published with a very high frequency so the chance to have two close messages (cloud and pose) should be high.

Anyway, my question is: `MessageFilter` should take care of this synchronization, but in the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter#Callback_Method) is using the TransformListener class directly to transform, but I can't because I need to transform a cloud using the PCL methods.
So what should I do to use it?

Something similar to what I did before with `lookupTransform`?

What is the difference in this case?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on Hydro

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182898/messagefilter-with-pointcloud-+-posemessage/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are processing data you should always use the timestamp associated with the data to transform it, never now().

If you use now() your transforms will be off by whatever is the aggregate latency in your data pipeline.

You are right that the MessageFilter is the preferred approach for waiting as it won't block your thread. It will give you the callback when the transform for the data is available and then you can do whatever operation you want inside the callback.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-07-04**:
so, to take the proper TF I should extract the timestamp from the cloud and use it inside the listener with something like: lookupTransform("source","dest",ros::Time(timestamp)) ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-05**:
yes, header.stamp is already a ros::Time object.

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-07-07**:
OK now I did it without using a MessageFilter. What is the difference between this doing the same with MessageFilter?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-07**:
A MessageFilter will hold data without blocking. If you have multiple parallel inputs which could be processed instead of blocking it will decrease latency.